# consulta no muestra ningun valor al ingresar el siguiente caracter "&"

Tags: sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente consulta ingreso el siguiente valor "Pregunta3&4", pero no devuelve nada en la consuta

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Podes ademas aclarar cuales son tus datos? que se supone que tendria que devolver?

Comment: el valor que ingreso en la tabla temporal " INSERT INTO @VariableTable VALUES(Pregunta3&4'')", pero cuando ingreso el siguiente caracter "&" no devuelve nada

Comment: A ver.. pon tu codigo como texto, no como imagen. Lo que no te funciona es el insert? no deberia generarte ningun problema ese caracter dentro de tu insert.. Creo que tenes que aclarar tu pregunta un poco mas.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el ampersand (&) genera un error en el XML que evita que funcione la conversión y por lo tanto la división de valores. No estoy seguro de como corregirlo, pero te dejó una alternativa que ha sido probada como una opción más eficiente.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table” produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
GO
```

El código y las mediciones originales las puedes encontrar en [este artículo en inglés](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

Y su uso queda en algo relativamente sencillo. Puedes cambiar los nombres de las columnas en la función si deseas que quede en algo en español.

```
SELECT s.ItemNumber, s.Item
FROM @VariableTabla
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K( nombre, @Delimiter) s
```